# Deserialise XML to Tree

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML data that I wish to build into a tree structure?

```
<DATA>
  <NODES>
    <NODE>
       <ID>1</ID>
       <CONTENT>Foo</CONTENT>
       <ChildrenIds>
           <Child>2</Child>
           <Child>3</Child>
       </ChildrenIds>
       <Level>1</Level>
    </NODE>
     <NODE>
       <ID>2</ID>
       <CONTENT>Foo</CONTENT>
       <ChildrenIds>
           <Child>4</Child>               
       </ChildrenIds>
    </NODE>
     <NODE>
       <ID>3</ID>
       <CONTENT>oo</CONTENT>
       <ChildrenIds>
         <Child>5</Child>
       </ChildrenIds>
    </NODE>
     <NODE>
       <ID>4</ID>
       <CONTENT>Doo</CONTENT>
       <ChildrenIds/>
    </NODE>
     <NODE>
       <ID>5</ID>
       <CONTENT>Koo</CONTENT>
       <ChildrenIds/>
    </NODE>
  </NODES>
</DATA>
```

What's the best way to parse this into a tree structure using LINQ?

I'm assuming that I'll firstly need to start with a tree object such as the below:

```
public class Tree
{
    public Tree()
    {
        ChildrenNodes = new List<TreeStructure>();
    }

    public List<Tree> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: And what about ChildrenNodes? Should they be a Tree type with the Id and Content and list of their subchilds or not? Seems different Your class and an xml tree structure.

Comment: The ChildrenNodes should contain the Nodes referenced in the ChildrenIds. So, in the above XML, I should have a Tree with Id = 1 and this tree will have ChildrenNodes with Id = 2 and Id = 3 and the Child with Id = 2 will have a ChildrenNodes with a Tree = 4 and so forth down the tree

Comment: Do you really need something which the FCL XML framework mechanisms cannot offer you? E.g. XmlDocument, Linq2Xml etc. Your tree looks like quite a general structure. Unless it offers some other rich behavior then perhaps it's not really worth designing.

Comment: Why not use [xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s(v=vs.80).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

```
usign system.runtime.serialization

[datacontract]
public class Tree
{
    public Tree()
    {
        ChildrenNodes = new List<TreeStructure>();
    }
    [datamember]
    public List<Tree> ChildrenNodes { get; set; }
    [datamember]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [datamember]
    public string Content {get; set;}
}

void serialize(Tree tree,string filename)
{
datacontractserializer serializer = new datacontracetserializer (typeof(Tree));
system.xml.xmltextwriter writer = new xmltextwriter(filename,Encoding.UTF32);
serializer.WriteObject(writer,tree);
writer.close();
}

void deserialize(ref Tree tree,string filename)
{
    xmltextreader reader = new xmltextreader*new streamreader(filename, Encoding.UTF32));
DataContracetSerializer deser = new datacontracetserializer(typeof(Tree));
trr = (Tree)deserializer.readObject(reader);
reader.close()
}
```

select the encoding

Comment: Afraid this will not serialise the ChildrenIds into a Tree node. I'm looking for a way to implement the specific logic to handle this?